# multiple processes, one mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, multiprocessing, mutex

I am currently working on a project that requires me to run two processes (P1 and P2) at the same time. Both P1 and P2 have multiple threads running. All of these threads should be able to write into one mutex protected log file.

What I have so far:
The FILE* is a global variable in P1, and I have used a mutex to protect it from more than one thread attempting to write to it. This seems to work fine.

Now I am wondering how I can get the threads from P2 to write to the same log file, while protecting it from simultaneous write attempts (from both P1 and P2). I might be really wrong on this, but I figured that if I just fork after declaring the log file pointer and the mutex, the mutex in P1 will only protect from multiple write attempts from threads in P1 and the mutex in P2 will only protect from multiple write attemps from threads in P2.
Is there an easy way of solving this? I would be really happy if someone could help me out with this, I've been trying many many things, without success.

EDIT: I did not know about SHARED INTER-PROCESS MUTEX. I will put my code up when I have something working.

Joe

Comment: Read about [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking).

Comment: Or use a shared inter-process mutex.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about inter-process mutexes. I thought they were strictly intra-process. I will look into it! Could anyone please tell me why my question is being downvoted? Is it because I am not showing code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As people commented, you can use a process-shared mutex. On Unix/Linux that involves creating a piece of shared memory that contains that mutex and mapping it in both processes.

On Linux though, you can rely on the fact that a blocking `write()` syscall into a file is atomic. That is, you can have multiple processes logging into the same file and as long as they pass complete lines into `write()` the lines won't be corrupted in the file. POSIX doesn't require such atomicity for files, however, I remember reading a comment by Linus Torvalds saying that a filesystem which didn't support this would not work well for Linux.